# copy a text file data to other one without first line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to copy a text file data which is like a table to the other one.
I want to copy to the other text file without the first line.Those data are spaced with space and look exactly like the following in excel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXOqo.png

I tried 2 method

first one is copy the whole thing in then find and remove that line which failed to write.

```py
with open('path1') as fin, open('path2', 'w') as fout:
    a=fin.read()
    fout.write(a)
```

second one is using deque, trying to follow the example to copy just the last 3 line first, then figure out to copy more line later.

```py
 collections import deque
with open('path1') as fin, open('path2', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(deque(fin, 3))
```

Both of them make the text file at path2 get erased and become blank.

Comment: You might want to look into https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way-

```
with open('path1', 'r') as reader, open('path2', 'w') as writer:
    reader.readline()  # read the first line and discard it
    rem_lines = reader.readlines()   # read all the remaining lines
    writer.writelines(rem_lines)     # write all the remaining lines to the second file
```

for big files, as reading the entire file in the memory might not be feasible, read the first file line by line and write to the second file.

```
with open('path1', 'r') as reader, open('path2', 'w') as writer:
    reader.readline()  # read the first line and discard it
    for line in reader:
        writer.write(line)
```

Comment: Not recommended for big files

Answer (score 0):

File objects are iterators, providing one line per iteration.
Therefore:

```
with open('path1') as fin, open('path2', 'w') as fout:
    next (fin)
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line)
```

i.e. simply skip the line by advancing one iteration

Answer (score -1):

You need to read all lines of `file1`. You will get list of lines in `file1`.

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as file:
    file1Contents = file.readlines()
```

After that, you can append `file1` without the first line into `file2`.

```
with open("file2.txt", "a") as file:
    file.writelines(file1Contents[1:]) # remove the first line of file1
```

This will be done. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not only reading all of the file is discouraged, slicing creates another instsnce of the contents,  duplicating the footprint of the data in memory!

Comment: @Pynchia : I never think that far before. And, it's good to know.

Comment: @CheukheiChan : file.writelines(file1Contents[1:]) will remove the first line IF you read file1.txt using readlines(). Unless you use read() or readline(), that will remove the first character or letter